# Gatsby not found

Tags: gatsby

I have installed gatsby in my mac using the gatsby documentation steps.
Using this command lines "npm install -g gatsby-cli". But I can't able to create gatsby project. I am facing "-bash: gatsby: command not found" error in my terminal. Also, try to "sudo npm install gatsby-cli -g" but I got the same error. I could see a similar problem asked on stack overflow, but the solution provided there is not helping me to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the command line `npx gatsby new gatsby-site`.

npx give you the possibility to use some CLI (like create-react-app or Gatsby) without installing the packaging on your side.